# Android NFC: one activity to send and one to receive only

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I want my ActivityNFCSender to send an integer to my ActivityNFCReceiver via NFC. The below code works. But there is a problem: when connection is established, BOTH activities display the prompt to send! But I want only the first one to be able to send (an integer) and  display the prompt. How to do it?

**ActivityNFCSender**:

```
public class ActivityNFCSender extends ActivityBase {

public static final String EXTRA_RES_ID = "res_id";

private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
private int mReservServerId;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReservServerId = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_RES_ID, 0);
}


public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();   

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(mNfcAdapter == null){
        messageDialogQuit(R.string.error_no_nfc);
    }
    else if(!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(true).setMessage(R.string.error_nfc_off)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.turn_on, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(settingsIntent);                          
                    }
                })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();    
                        finish();
                    }
                })                  
            .create().show();
    }
    else{           
        //Set sending
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(ActivityNFCSender.this,  getIntAsNdef(mReservServerId));
    }
}

public void onPause(){      
    if(mNfcAdapter != null && mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
    }
    super.onPause();        
}


private NdefMessage getIntAsNdef(int pInt) {
    byte[] textBytes = (pInt+"").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    NdefRecord textRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "text/plain".getBytes(), new byte[] {}, textBytes);
    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        textRecord
    });
}
```

**ActivityNFCReceiver**:

```
public class ActivityNFCReceiver extends ActivityBase {

private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
private PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;
private IntentFilter[] mNdefExchangeFilters;    


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.nfcTVStatus)).setText(R.string.receiving);
}


public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();   

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(mNfcAdapter == null){
        messageDialogQuit(R.string.error_no_nfc);
    }
    else if(!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(true).setMessage(R.string.error_nfc_off)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.turn_on, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(settingsIntent);                          
                    }
                })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();    
                        finish();
                    }
                })                  
            .create().show();
    }
    else{           
        mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        // Intent filters for exchanging over p2p.
        IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndefDetected.addDataType("text/plain");
        } 
        catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mNdefExchangeFilters = new IntentFilter[] { ndefDetected };

        //set receiving
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(ActivityNFCReceiver.this, mNfcPendingIntent, mNdefExchangeFilters, null);
    }
}

public void onPause(){      
    if(mNfcAdapter != null && mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(ActivityNFCReceiver.this);
    }
    super.onPause();        
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        NdefMessage[] msgs = getNdefMessages(intent);
        if(msgs.length > 0){
            try{
                NdefRecord firstRecord = msgs[0].getRecords()[0];
                byte[] payload = firstRecord.getPayload();
                String str = new String(payload, Charset.forName("UTF8"));

                int reservServerId = Integer.parseInt(str);
                returnResult(reservServerId);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                messageDialog(R.string.error_during_NFC);
            }
        }
    }
}


public void onCancelClicked(View pV){
    finish();
}

private NdefMessage[] getNdefMessages(Intent intent) {
    // Parse the intent
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            // Unknown tag type
            byte[] empty = new byte[] {};
            NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, empty);
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { record });
            msgs = new NdefMessage[] { msg };
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unknown intent.");
        finish();
    }
    return msgs;
}


private void returnResult(int pResServerId){
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra(ActivityCompanySubMenu.EXTRA_RES_SERVER_ID, pResServerId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the Beam UI for a specific activity (i.e. your `ActivityNFCReceiver`) by using the `NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    [...]

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
    }
}
```

Be aware that the `enableForegroundNdefPush` method has been deprecated since Android 4.0 (API level 14) and that pretty much all Android devices that support NFC use Android 4.0 or later.

---

While disabling the Beam UI that way works on Nexus devices and is the officially documented way to go (see [setNdefPushMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessage%28android.nfc.NdefMessage,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29)):

> If setNdefPushMessage(...) is called with a null NDEF message [...] then NDEF push will be completely disabled for the specified activity(s). This also disables any default NDEF message the Android OS would have otherwise sent on your behalf for those activity(s).

it seems that -- unfortunately -- this does not work for some Android devices' NFC implementation. For instance, it does not work on Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3.

Comment: I changed the code and added  mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);   just after  mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(ActivityNFCReceiver.this, mNfcPendingIntent, mNdefExchangeFilters, null);  in the receiver activity, but same result: both devices display the prompt to SEND.  I might be wrong, but I presume enableForegroundDispatch() function is to enable RECEIVING. I want the receiver activity to be in foreground and RECEIVE the integer.

Comment: By the way, ANY activity displays this system prompt (the image of the activity becomes smaller and Android asks me if I want to send. What? I don't know).   Thanks for your response so far and I hope you can help me with it further...

Comment: In general you should use setNdefPushMessage as early as possible in your activity life-cylce (i.e. in `onCreate()`). However, that does not explain why the Beam UI is show in your case. WHat Anadroid version are you using?

Comment: I added mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
  if(mNfcAdapter != null){
   mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
  }
to onCreate() of ActivityNFCReceiver but still the same problem exists. I disabled the code in onResume, just for test - still the same. The device is Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3 . The sender is a Nexus7 with Android 4.4.2    But anyway: the prompt to send appears at EVERY activity regardless if it is NFC enabled or not.

Comment: NFC is *always* enabled (unless you disable NFC functionality completely through the Android settings menu). By default an activity will try to send an Android Application Record in order to start the same app on the other device (hence the Beam UI). Setting the NDEF message to `null` with the `setNdefPushMessage` method is supposed to disable this default behavior. This seems to work on the Nexus devices I tried.

Comment: OK, I switched the devices (Galaxy is the sender, Nexus is the receiver) and now your solution works. Also, disabling Beam on the receiver also solves the problem.

Comment: It's interesting that disabling Beam on the receiver works (I would have expected that this also prevents messages to be received over Beam). It's not really surprising that the S3 does not behave like other phones. I'll add a comment on that to my answer if that's okay for you.